# How to stop skype crashing when loading large chatroom with thousands of messages?

Tags: skype

I'm a member of a skype chatroom with a few hundred members that is used for general discussion of a certain technical field so we can all help each other. The chatroom is never closed but rather continues to run ad infinitum and is used around the clock by an ever-rotating group of people around the world.

What this means is that anytime I turn Skype off and on again now, I have to load thousands of new messages that took place over the last 12 hours. On Linux this works okay; on Windows it takes several minutes to load the client; and on Mac it crashes the client completely.

Is there any way to get it to NOT load the new messages?

Comment: No; I would even dare say you are using Skype in a way it wasn't designed for.  Why not use IRC?

Comment: I agree....just hoping I can make it work. I'm not in control of this room.